# porque marca error con la etiqueta record

Tags: mvc, xml, odoo

Estoy añadiendo una pestaña a la vista del modelo de odoo que estoy modficando pero a la hora de actualizar el modulo me manda un error de que hay un record extra

Adjunto codigo:

````
```<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


  <odoo>

<record id="view_mti_bascula_form" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">Formulario Bascula</field>
    <field name="model">mti_bascula</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form>
            <sheet>
                <group style="display:flex;">
                <field name="Proovedor_id" domain="[('category_id', 'in', [categoria_Proovedor_id])]"
                        options="{'no_create': True, 'no_open': True}"/>
                <field name="categoria_Proovedor_id" invisible="1"/>
                </group>
                <group style="display:flex;">
                    <field name="Operador"/>
                    <field name="Placas_Trac"/>
                </group>
                <group style="display:flex;">
                    <field name="Carta_porte" />
                    <field name="Destino" />
                    <field name="Via" required="1" />
                </group>
                 <group style="display:flex;">
                     <field name="Remitente"/>
                     <field name="Consignado"/>
                 </group>
                <div style="display:flex;">
                    <group>
                        <field name="Recibe"/>
                        <field name="Ejecutivo"/>
                        <field name="Mercancia"/>
                        <field name="Peso_bruto"/>
                    </group>
                </div>
                <button string="Traer Peso" type="object" name="traer_peso" class="oe_highlight"/>

                 <separator string="Detalles"/>

                <notebook>
                    <page string="detalles_bascula">
                        <group>
                            <field name="peso_id">
                                <tree editable="botom">
                                    <field name="Ancho"/>
                                    <field name="Alto"/>
                                    <field name="Volumen"/>
                                    <field name="Peso_Bruto"/>
                                    <field name="Descripcion"/>
                                    <field name="Palletizado" required="1" />
                                    <field name="Emplayado" required="1" />
                                    <field name="Flejado" required="1" />
                                    <field name="Sello" required="1" />
                                </tree>
                            </field>
                        </group>
                    </page>
                </notebook>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>


<record id="mti_bascula" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Bascula</field>
    <field name="res_model">mti_bascula</field>
    <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
</record>


<menuitem id="mti_menu_bascula" name="Bascula" parent="stock.menu_stock_root"  sequence="1"/>
<menuitem  action="mti_bascula" parent="mti_menu_bascula" id="bascula_menu" name="Bascula"   sequence="2"/>

             </odoo>```
````

la verda dno se porque manda ese error estoy batallando mucho con esa pestaña como le podria hacer o de que forma puedo resolver ese error porque en la terminal arroja quie hay un record extra antes mandaba otros errores con el modelo epro los pude resolver pero siempre que ya no hay erro me regresa al mismo de que hay una etiqueta record extra pero reviso el codigo y no hay nada

Comment: los puse asi para evitar poner la etiqueta completa entonces si tendria que pner de forma nomral?

Comment: listo funciono gracias

Comment: Me alegro de haberte ayudado, no sé qué hice, pero se borraron los comentarios anteriores... ;-D

Comment: si se borraron ntp